# get last time activity with sum, group and subquery

Tags: oracle, logic, subquery

any body can help me please? i want to querying from my table, the purpose is to show which employees are selling over 100 pieces. i have done that query and works,

but the problem arises when **I want to display the last time of sale of each employee** (who sell goods over 100 pieces)

i have table TBL_SALES like

```
no   employee_id   name          pieces   sl_time
---|-------------|-------------|--------|----------
1  |     1       | bungdito    | 60     | 2012-03-29 22:20
2  |     1       | bungdito    | 40     | 2012-03-05 18:00
3  |     1       | bungdito    | 50     | 2012-02-18 08:00
4  |     2       | addheat     | 120    | 2012-02-12 09:30
5  |     3       | angga       | 20     | 2012-01-18 10:45
6  |     4       | dimas       | 50     | 2012-01-01 08:30
```

when i use query like this

```
select * from 
( 
  select EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, sum(PIECES) PIECES from 
  ( 
    select EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, PIECES
    from DB_SCHEMA.TBL_SALES 
  )  
  group by EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME
) where PIECES > 100
```

i have **this correct result**

```
 employee_id   name          pieces 
-------------|-------------|--------
     1       | bungdito    | 150    
     2       | addheat     | 120
```

**the result above is correct**,

but what **I need** is **complete with each employees last transaction time**

i have tried to make query **but still not correct**

```
select * from 
( 
  select EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, sum(PIECES) PIECES, SL_TIME

  ( 
    select EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, PIECES,(select max(WAKTU) SL_TIME from DB_USER.TR_PELANGGARAN where TB_SALES.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE_ID from TB_SALES) SL_TIME
    from DB_SCHEMA.TBL_SALES 
  )  
  group by EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, SL_TIME
) where PIECES > 100
```

using that query **i still have the wrong result** (see the sl_time is same between bungdito and addheat) like :

```
    employee_id   name          pieces   sl_time
   -------------|-------------|--------|----------
        1       | bungdito    | 150    | 2012-03-29 22:20
        2       | addheat     | 120    | 2012-03-29 22:20
```

what i need is like this below:

```
employee_id   name          pieces   sl_time
-------------|-------------|--------|----------
     1       | bungdito    | 150    | 2012-03-29 22:20
     2       | addheat     | 120    | 2012-02-12 09:30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  select EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, sum(PIECES) PIECES, MAX(SL_TIME)
  from DB_SCHEMA.TBL_SALES   
  group by EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME
  having sum(PIECES) > 100
```

Comment: whats do you mean with B in MAX(B.SL_TIME) ?

Comment: its works when i delete [having pieces > 100], with [having pieces > 100] i've got error "not a GROUP BY expression".. why?

Comment: aha, you've forget the sum in [having sum(PIECES) > 100]

Comment: that's right, I forgot it was oracle. It's solved now. Note that you don't need a subquery to use both aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from 
( 
  select EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, sl_time
        , sum(PIECES)  over(partition by EMPLOYEE_ID)  SUM_PIECES 
        , max(sl_time) over(partition by EMPLOYEE_ID)  last_sl_time
  from       
    DB_SCHEMA.TBL_SALES 
) 
where SUM_PIECES > 100
and    last_sl_time = sl_time
;
```

Comment: amazing, it's works.. have I told you if i'm newbie in oracle :p

Comment: I don't think the nested query is necessary.

Comment: This query is *not* equivalent to the original query.  The SUM and last time are taken *before* the WHERE clause is applied.  The solution is simple . . . just move the WHERE clause inside the subquery.